# Как использовать const с auto?

Tags: c++, const, auto

Есть вот такой код для примера:

```
typedef int* iter;
typedef const int* c_iter;
int arr[]{1, 2, 3, 4};

iter arrbegin()
{ return arr; }

int main()
{
   const auto it = arrbegin();
   it++;
   return 0;
}
```

И он выбивает ошибку (изменение константных данных) но я немного в замешательстве. Насколько я понимаю данный код эквивалентен этому:

```
const iter it = arrbegin ();
```

Но разве `const iter` не эквивалентен `iter_const`? Опытным путем я уже понял, что нет, но мне не понятно: почему нет?

Comment: Это примерно такое же различие, как и "константный указатель" и "указатель на константный объект".

Comment: А все потому, что люди пишут (и читают) const не с той стороны. В С/C++ объявления пишутся и читаются по спиральному правилу, в данном случае справа налево.

Comment: `c_iter it =  arrbegin();` - это приведёт указатель `iter` к другому типу спокойно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда вы добавляете `const` к typedef-у, он добавляется не слева (и не справа), а *на верхний уровень*.

Это становится понятнее, если расписать словами значения типов:

`typedef int* iter;` - "iter - это указатель на `int`".

`const iter` - "константный `iter`", т.е. "константный указатель на `int`".

А "константный указатель на `int`" - это `int *const`, поэтому как раз такой тип вы и получаете. (В противоположность `const int *` - указателю на константный `int`.)